# ListPlot[Transpose[{xx,yy}]] returns blank plot

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

This is complete mystery for me, but I am unable to plot the following data... I have two lists, that I want to ListPlot. The data is created in the following way (I edited the code for more clarity):

```
xx = Table[i, {i, 1.485, 1.5, .001}];
yy = Table[0, {i, Length[xx]}];
```

Then, I run a For on all the elements of yy to change their value. In the end, I get the following list:

```
yy = {2.2005*10^(-3),2.34527*10^(-3),2.50062*10^(-3),2.66517*10^(-3),2.83694*10^(-3),3.01328*10^(-3),3.19072*10^(-3),3.36471*10^(-3),3.52911*10^(-3),3.6752*10^(-3),3.7894*10^(-3),3.84831*10^(-3),3.80618*10^(-3),3.55756*10^(-3),2.79023*10^(-3),0.}
```

The thing is, when I try to

```
ListPlot[Transpose[{xx,yy}]
```

it does not work. I have to manually copy (copy as plain text) the generated list in place of yy, and then it works.

What's wrong with my yy? If needed I will copy the code that I use to change that list, but it is quite long... So if anybody knows that this kind of behavior is typical of something, please let me know.

Edited: xx and yy have the same length, sorry about that.

Also, when I try

```
ListPlot[Transpose[{xx,xx}]]
```

I do get a (obviously linear) plot, which means that everything is fine with xx, but whenever I try to add yy somewhere, MMA returns an empty plot.

Edit 2: as requested, here is the output of Transpose[{xx,yy}]:

```
{{1.485,2.2005*10^(-3)},{1.486,2.34527*10^(-3)},{1.487,2.50062*10^(-3)},{1.488,2.66517*10^(-3)},{1.489,2.83694*10^(-3)},{1.49,3.01328*10^(-3)},{1.491,3.19072*10^(-3)},{1.492,3.36471*10^(-3)},{1.493,3.52911*10^(-3)},{1.494,3.6752*10^(-3)},{1.495,3.7894*10^(-3)},{1.496,3.84831*10^(-3)},{1.497,3.80618*10^(-3)},{1.498,3.55756*10^(-3)},{1.499,2.79023*10^(-3)},{1.5,0.}}
```

and a screenshot of it as well (just in case):

[image: Screenshot of xx and yy]

Edit 3: I forgot the FullForm. Here we go, and I guess I see that the problem comes from there...

```
List[List[1.485`,ScientificForm[0.002200504961592269`]],List[1.486`,ScientificForm[0.002345269356606834`]],List[1.487`,ScientificForm[0.0025006194693353036`]],List[1.488`,ScientificForm[0.0026651682379572796`]],List[1.489`,ScientificForm[0.002836940677699209`]],List[1.49`,ScientificForm[0.0030132826042305045`]],List[1.491`,ScientificForm[0.0031907205430207306`]],List[1.492`,ScientificForm[0.003364706805684322`]],List[1.493`,ScientificForm[0.003529114711632648`]],List[1.494`,ScientificForm[0.00367520103764892`]],List[1.495`,ScientificForm[0.0037893969768483197`]],List[1.496`,ScientificForm[0.0038483114614672803`]],List[1.497`,ScientificForm[0.0038061835870495412`]],List[1.498`,ScientificForm[0.003557560962432392`]],List[1.499`,ScientificForm[0.0027902318774610966`]],List[1.5`,ScientificForm[0.`]]]
```

[image]

Comment: At least for the lists you have given `xx` and `yy` are of different length and so cannot be transposed. Don't you get a error message telling you that?

Comment: Check the `Length` of your `xx` vs `yy`. You will see that there is a slight difference. Your `xx` has 91 element whilst `yy` has only 16. Therefore it fails when you `Transpose` it

Comment: Oops sorry I edited the question to make it more lisible, but in the end created an error... xx and yy have the same length in my code. Edit: I edited my question, thanks for the catch and sorry about that.

Comment: Try this and see if it works: `ListPlot[Transpose[{xx[[;; 16]], yy}]]`, if it does it will reinforce what's been said that `xx` and `yy` are of different lengths.

Comment: I tried, it does not work.

Comment: Can you include the complete output of `Transpose[{xx,yy}] // FullForm` in your question?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard it seems indeed that the FullForm shows that my yy is written in ScientificForm. I guess the problem comes from there...

Comment: Formatting wrappers (like `ScientificForm`) will indeed cause problems; in fact they appear to be one of the most common sources of problems.  A frequent example is someone setting `m = {{1,2}, {3,4}} // MatrixForm` and then wondering why `m` does not act like a matrix. The documentation and software should in my opinion do a better job of warning people of this.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, thanks, your good intuition has helped me to solve my problem! You can write an answer about this and I'll approve it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your original post, the data you've provided for `xx` and `yy` (after you've applied some function to derive the values you've presented) are of inconsistent lengths. Therefore, when you apply `Transpose` it does not work and throws an error. Below is a simple example.

**Example**

```
x = RandomInteger[{1, 100}, 100]; (*Length: 100*)
y = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 100]; (*Length: 100*)
```

**Output**

```
ListPlot[Transpose[{x, y}]]
```

[image: example]

**EDIT**

Based on the information you've provided in your original post, here is a `Plot` I get.

**Code**

```
xx = Table[i, {i, 1.485, 1.5, .001}];
yy = {2.2005*10^(-3), 2.34527*10^(-3), 2.50062*10^(-3), 
   2.66517*10^(-3), 2.83694*10^(-3), 3.01328*10^(-3), 3.19072*10^(-3),
    3.36471*10^(-3), 3.52911*10^(-3), 3.6752*10^(-3), 3.7894*10^(-3), 
   3.84831*10^(-3), 3.80618*10^(-3), 3.55756*10^(-3), 2.79023*10^(-3),
    0.};

Length @ # & /@ {xx, yy} (* {91, 16*)

ListPlot[Transpose[{xx[[;; 16]], yy}]]
```

**Output**

[image: example 2]

Comment: Yes, sorry, that was a mistake on my side. I did not copy correctly xx. xx and yy in my code are of the same length. When I use ListPlot[Transpose[{xx,xx}]], I get a (linear plot), but the plot gets empty whenever I try to add yy in there.

Comment: Try `ListPlot[Transpose[{xx[[;;16]],yy[[;;16]]}]]` , does it work?